# Добавление столбца TD в таблицу TABLE каждые 5 секунд через Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Есть код:

> `<table>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td id="3"></td>
> <td id="2"></td>
> <td id="1"></td>
> </tr>
> </tbody
> </table>`

Мне необходимо, чтобы каждые 5 секунд к таблице добавлялся новый элемент TD (то есть новый столбец). В данном случае после выполнения такой функции вместо трёх столбцов TD должен появится четвёртый, который был бы перед трёмя, уже существующими столбцами. Можно ли в Javascript сделать такую функцию, которая выглядела бы примерно так:

> `function func() {
> /*Здесь тот самый скрипт, который нужен*/
> }
> setTimeout(func, 5000);
> }`

Если это возможно, то скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать этот скрипт...

Comment: определитесь с условием, в комментарии и в скрипте это каждые 5 секунд, а в заголовке по кнопке

Comment: Точно. Я уже запутался с этими скриптами. Сейчас исправлю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/5vss6zLm/) можно сделать, для селектора и добавления использую jQuery, но думаю есть методы и на чистом JS.

```
var i = 4; // Чтобы добавлять элементы с разными айдишниками и данными внутри
function func() {
    $('table > tbody > tr').prepend('<td id="'+ i +'">'+  i +'</td>'); // Чтобы добавлять ячейки в конец строки нyжно использовать функцию append()
    i++;
}
setInterval(func, 1000); // Чтобы функция повторялась постоянно нужно использовать setInterval(), в примере поставил 1000 для наглядности
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень помогли.